# Next.js SSR/ISR creating HTML static file for non-static page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, incremental-build

What would cause a static HTML to be created for a non-static page using Next.js? I'm unsure if it's causing any issues, but I noticed this was happening while troubleshooting an issue with this specific page. Is this expected?

What I mean is that we have one page, let's call it "page1", that does not have the `getStaticPaths()` or `getStaticProps()` functions.

This page *does* rely on server-side data, but does not make use of `getInitialProps()` or `getServerSideProps()` as they are deprecated.

When I `cd` into the build directory I can see the `.next/server/pages/page1.html` - is this expected? There is no `page1.json` file. If not, what would cause this HTML file to be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's expected. It's Next.js' [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) at play.

If your page does not contain `getServerSideProps`/`getInitialProps`, then Next.js will automatically statically optimize the page and prerender it as static HTML.

From the docs:

> If `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps` is present in a page, Next.js
> will switch to render the page on-demand, per-request (meaning
> Server-Side Rendering).
>
> If the above is not the case, Next.js will statically optimize your
> page automatically by prerendering the page to static HTML.
>
> During prerendering, the router's query object will be empty since we
> do not have query information to provide during this phase. After
> hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to
> provide the route parameters in the query object.
>
> `next build` will emit `.html` files for statically optimized pages.